# Mysterious whitespace that isn't a space in character string

Tags: r

I have a character string. Suppose the value looks like " banana" - it appears to be prepended by whitespace. However, I can't remove the whitespace with

```
trimws(mystring)
```

and if I try

```
substr(mystring,1,1) == " "
```

it returns FALSE. Thus, I have a blank space which is not a space (" "). How do I figure out what it is? Is it a tab? I imported the culprit data from an excel file, in case that matters.

edit:

```
substr(mystring,1,1) == "\U00A0"
```

returns TRUE. thanks

Comment: What does `substr(mystring,1,1)` return? If it's a tab you could use `gsub('^(\\t|\\s)*|(\\t|\\s)*$', '', mystring)` to replace all tabs and spaces at the start and end of your string. As an alternative to trimws.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's probably a non-ASCII space, for example a non-breaking space (`"\u00A0"`). You can use `utf8::utf8_print(mystring, utf8 = FALSE)` to find out what character it is, and you can probably delete it with `gsub("^[[:space:]]*", "", mystring)`.