# R does not recognize whitespace

Tags: r

I'm trying to extract the first word of that name, but I'm not able to because R is not recognizing whitespace.

```
library(stringr)

name <- x[76,3]
name
[1] "Byrsonima crispa A.Juss."

word(name,1)
[1] "Byrsonima crispa A.Juss."

str_count(name," ")
[1] 0
```

Comment: What does `charToRaw(name)` vs `charToRaw("Byrsonima crispa A.Juss.")` return?  You may be dealing with a less common type of whitespace.  You could try `str_count(name, "\\h")` which matches all horizontal whitespace.

Comment: Oddly enough it works for me here. `name <- "Byrsonima crispa A.Juss."; str_count(name," ")` returns `[1] 2`. R 4.2.0, stringr 1.4.0, locale en_US.UTF-8, macOS.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi, when I run ```word(name,1,sep="\\s")``` it worked, I was able to extract the first word. With ```sep=" "```, the function only worked for a few words. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to specify white space as Regex pattern:

```
str_count("Byrsonima crispa A.Juss.", "\\s")
#[1] 2

word("Byrsonima crispa A.Juss.", 1, sep = "\\s")
#[1] "Byrsonima"
```

---

**Update:**

I am also curious about what's causing `" "` to fail (because I can't reproduce what you reported; `" "` works fine for me). It is not good enough for you to reply to me that `" "` only worked for some of your strings but not all of them. We want to investigate the reason, not just offering a working solution.

Comment: Found this: [Mysterious whitespace that isn't a space in character string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47559676/4891738)